# Controller's action with dictionary as parameter stripping to dot

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Action that receives a class with a dictionary in its properties:

```
public ActionResult TestAction(TestClass testClass)
{
    return View();
}

public class TestClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValues { get; set; }
}
```

If I do a post to my action with the following JSON:

```
{
  "KeyValues": {
    "test.withDoT": "testWithDot"
  }
}
```

The key in my dictionary is stripped to the dot and has nothing in the value.

[image]

Trying without the dot works. How can I do a post with a dot in a `Dictionary<string, string>` with MVC?

Comment: You could _try_ escaping the dot:  `"test\.withDoT": "testWithDot"`

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives a 500 error with the message "Unrecognized escape sequence."

Comment: Unless you create a custom `ModelBinder`, I doubt you can. The `DefaultModelBinder` identifies the dot as property separator. You could try `{ KeyValues[0].Key: 'test.withDoT', KeyValues[0].Value: 'testWithDot' }` to see if that will bind

Comment: If the json code/litertal is in javascript, then you could give a try to \\. (backslash backslash dot)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Doesn't work also, it gives a 500 error with the message "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected."

Comment: Stephen: it is working without the dot. We do not want interpret it as property, instead just use dot as a literal.

Comment: @g.pickardou Doesn't work, it is still stipped to the dot, but now I have a \ at the end of the key

Comment: @g.pickardou, Yes I know, but its the `DefaultModelbinder` which will identify it as a property separator

Comment: btw 'dot' is not a legal char in identifiers. Yes I know it is a _key_ in the C# dictionary, but in the json part (and javascript) it could be in the _identifier_ syntax role.

Comment: @AlexandrePepin, Sorry, you need to quote all values - it should be `{ 'KeyValues[0].Key': 'test.withDoT', 'KeyValues[0].Value': 'testWithDot' }` - refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OLglBG)

Comment: I have doubt we can find a json serializer which will serialize this way out of the box... Seems to be spending unnecessary a lot of time, and making the code unnecessary more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We gave a blind try supposing that there is a regex parser somewhere in the deep (well it was minimal the chance) and to escape 'dot'.

After thinking a while I concluded: dot is not a legal char in identifiers. Yes I know it is a *key* in the C# dictionary, but in the json part (and javascript) it could be in the identifier syntax role.

So I strongly suggest to replace client side the `.` (dot) with an escape sequence like `_dot_` and replace back it in server side. Performance will suffer of course.

Comment: Pepin, I was sure you expected better answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

Change the javascript to

```
var data = { 'KeyValues[0].Key': 'test.withDoT', 'KeyValues[0].Value': 'testWithDot' };
```

and then post using

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TestAction")', data, function(data) { ...`
```

Comment: It works, but requires lots of changes in the serialization in javascript